# move a div with display flex to around the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a while, maybe i'm not searching correctly, can you please help with something

As it can be seen in the below image, i want to move those arrows to that position
i have display flex set, see code below

[image: arrows]

```
<div class="divarrows">
   <p class="arrow1">&#9655;</p>
   <p class="arrow2">&#9655;</p>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.arrow1 {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow1:hover, .arrow2:hover {
    color: #54B3A1;
}

.divarrows{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 30px;
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: You need to modify the parent of divarrows. Use the devtools to inspect how are things aligning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u really need to move those arrows up, it can be done without flexbox. Try using  margin-top with a negative value. For example (see code below)

```css
.arrow1 {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -350px;     
}

.arrow2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -350px;
}

.arrow1:hover, .arrow2:hover {
    color: #54B3A1;
}

.divarrows{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 30px;
    align-self: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="divarrows">
   <p class="arrow1">&#9655;</p>
   <p class="arrow2">&#9655;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i feel dumb now lol, why haven't i tought of that, its so simple hehe. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Adding align-items: center to divarrows should fix the problem.

```
.divarrows{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 30px;
    align-self: center;
}
```

If you have some kind of conflict with other element which need to be at the top for example, you can simply target each arrows:

```
.arrow1, .arrow2 {
    align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that what you see is not the full page, there is more content if i scroll down so it won't work like this

Comment: Could you provide a link or maybe more or your html? The size of your page does not change anything, once you add display: flex to the divarrows element, the arrows will stay in the middle of this element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the align-items :center will fix the problem
`.arrow1,.arrow2{align-self;center;}`

Comment: i tried, it won't work, my page is muuch longer, need to scroll down, i forgot to mention that